# Video files appears green instead of pink

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So, once in a while a video file (.mkv) will appear green (Executable or recognized data file) instead of pink (Graphic image file).  I run mediainfo on the file and bitrate, length, framerate all seem to be good.  Are there any issues with the file? I feel as if a recognized video format file should not appear green instead of pink.

(Playing the file is not an option, it's on a vps)

Comment: `chmod -x file.mkv`

Answer (score 0):

The green colour (by default) indicates that the file is executable. If you run `ls *.mkv`, you can see that the green ones have at least one of the `x` permission bits set. While this won’t affect your ability to play the video files, it makes sense to fix their file access permissions (since video files should not – nor can’t – be executed as programs). To remove the executable permission from all `.mkv` files in the current directory, run

```
chmod -x *.mkv
```